# Free result and close connection before unsetting the mysql object or just unsetting would destroy the object n free up the resources?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am learning php/mysql. I don't seem to find a definitive answer to some of the q's.. Can u clarify me some of them or point me to a reliable source. thanks.

(1) If i don't need the database object any more, does unsetting the object release all the associated resources (connection / memory holding resutls etc.) or do i have to call `$mysqliResult->free()` and/or `$mysqliObj->close()` before calling `unset($mysqliObj)`.

(2) Also if i am using a database abstraction layer where a member of abstraction class holds the mysqli object, does unsetting the `$dbAbstractionObj` free up the mysql connection for other script calls or do i have to  call `$this->mysqli->close()` within the destructor of database abstraction class... I know that PHP cleans up everything at the end of script execution, but i would like to know if theres a benefit to doing those while the script is running where large amount of data are fetchd and processd... Examples of what i am trying to say:

(1)

```
$mysqli = new Mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);
$result = $mysqli->query('...');
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

/* Now if i don't need $mysqli any futher but would be doing
other stuff on $data that might take a while, do I just */
unset($mysqli)

/* OR */
$result->free();
$mysqli->kill($mysqli->thread_id);
$mysqli->close();
unset($mysqli);

?>
```

(2)

```
<?php

class Database {
    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct(array $config) {
        if (!$this->mysqli = new mysqli($config['host'], $config['user'], $config['pass'], $config['database'])) {
            throw new Exception("Couldn't connect to database");
        }
    }

    /* do i need a destructor to close the connection when i unset the
    Database object... like */
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->mysqli->kill($this->mysqli->thread_id);
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }

    /* other methods for select, update, insert, delete */
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have an idea of killing a thread at all?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: while i was searching for this, I read it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You may only have one prepared statement/execution at a time when using mysqli. If you try to open and execute two prepared statements without closing you will generate an error.
Any resources you explicitly open past your db abstractor should be dealt with by you during execution time. That is, if you open a connection using the info in the abstractor it is best practice to explicitly close it (but not unset the base resource itself), thereby freeing the resource associated with it. Having a basic mysql-connection is not very resource consuming, but keeping a large number of un-closed connections to your mysql server can cause it to cease accepting connections (depending on config). Most executions, upon completion, will automatically free the associated mysql resources if they aren't explicitly freed by you during runtime.

Tell me if this helps,